# How to create multiple columns filled with 0 in an xts object in R?

Tags: r, xts

I would like to create multiple columns filled with zeroes in one xts object. Manually I can use this code :

```
> class(data)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
> colnames(data)
 [1] "A"  "B"
>  data$C <- 0
> colnames(data)
 [1] "A"  "B"  "C"
```

But unfortunately when in a `for` loop the `i` is interpreted as an object name instead of a variable.

```
> symbols
[1] "D"  "E"  "F"
for (i in symbols) {
    data$i <- 0
}
> colnames(data)
> [1] "A"  "B"  "C"  "i"
```

When I use `[[`, the programmatic equivalent of `$` then `colnames(data)` returns `NULL`.

Finally I try with the `apply` family of functions like below but it doesn't work as expected.

```
> sapply(symbols,  function(i) {data$i <- 0})
D E F 
0 0 0
```

What could be the best solution to do this ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, when I try it gives an error saying `Error in if (length(c(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)) == 6 && c(year,  : 
  missing Value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same error with `[i]`

Comment: Try `for (i in symbols) data<-do.call(cbind,setNames(list(data,0),c("",i)))`. Or better yet, without loops: `do.call(cbind,setNames(c(list(data),rep(list(0),length(symbols))),c("",symbols)))`

Comment: Thank you very much Nicola, both solutions you propose work perfectly :)

Comment: Maybe it is better to mark this question as _answered_, do you mind if I write it for you ? or perhaps you already plan to do it

Comment: I made an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
do.call(cbind,setNames(c(list(data),rep(list(0),length(symbols))),
                       c("",symbols)‌​))
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend creating a new xts object with the desired column names and values, then `merge` that with the original data.

```
require(xts)
data <- xts(cbind(A=1:5,B=5:1), Sys.Date()-5:1)
symbols <- LETTERS[3:6]
zeros <- xts(matrix(0,nrow(data),length(symbols)),
             index(data), dimnames=list(NULL,symbols))
data <- merge(data, zeros)
```

That makes what is being done explicit, and therefore less confusing for future you. :)